# UEFI Application for pci link test

Tags: uefi, pci-e, edk2

I am trying to write a uefi applcation to print pci link status for all the pci device. I am able to locate all the pci devices but how do i get the status link speed for these?

I am using pciIoprotocol . I have my edk2 environment set up. I also want to know whether it is possible to get these info

Comment: It is a while since I looked at the various EDKII PCI structures so I could be wrong but have you looked at `CurrentLinkSpeed` in `PCI_REG_PCIE_LINK_STATUS`? See `PciExpress21.h`.

Comment: @fpmurphy thanks. I am having difficulty in finding the adress for LinkStatusRegister. I guess i have to use the capability pointer for that.I am able to find all pci device using Status = gBS->HandleProtocol(HandleBuffer[Index],
                                 &gEfiPciIoProtocolGuid,
                                 (VOID**)&PciIo);
Now i want to go through all this devices and find the link speed. Can you provide any input on this. Thanks in advance.